'importhtml' function on google sheets is only returning headers but not data from the body of the table?
I am trying to extract the data from a table on the following website:
https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=20&type=1&season=2024&month=2&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&pagenum=1&pageitems=250
On my google sheet, I have entered
=importhtml("https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/major-league?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=20&type=1&season=2024&month=2&season1=2024&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&pagenum=1&pageitems=250","TABLE",0)
It is working and returning the correct table but is only showing the headers at the top of the table but none of the data.
Might anyone know why I can only import the table? Aloa, how I can import the table AND import the data from the table into Google Sheets? z

